How much performance of current hardware is left out due to SW (higher-level programming languages)?
I was wondering how much potential performance of our current HW is unused due to higher level programming languages (here I consider C and C++ to be high level languages).
Of course I know that it would be impossible and totally unproductive, but how much more performance could we squeeze out of current HW if everything (and I mean everything from user apps down to kernel) was hand written (by really smart dev - so writing optimized) in machine code?
Are we talking single percentage points better performance? Orders of magnitude better performance?
Just wondering about if better SW can bring more uplift than new node technology (3nm to 2nm)

The question is to vague to be answered precisely. The thing is it strongly depends of the actual algorithm to be implemented. Actually, from one domain to another, the answer can be very different. There is no way to average such a thing (eg. what matters the most: number of line of code, execution frequency, kind of algorithm, etc.). The exact target language also matter (for example even higher level languages like Java, Python or just C/C++ as mentioned). Not to mention de ISA and the target CPU architecture (some of them are harder for human to use than others).

Here is a general vague short answer. In some cases, C codes with optimized compilers give very good results and human can hardly do better (note it depends of the time taken to optimize the code because in some case it takes few days to write a bit better code that a compiler generated in few seconds but let's assume time is not a problem). This happens for scalar code that does not benefit much from special instruction sets or any low-level tricks (e.g. bit hacks). This is even more true on embedded ARM/RISC-V systems.

In some other cases, the gap can be really HUGE. A typical use case is the use of SIMD instruction. Mainstream compiler often poorly auto-vectorize complex codes. The benefit is dependent of many parameter (mainly the ISA, exact compiler and algorithm) but the gap can be of 1~2 order of magnitude in this case. This is especially true when compilers generate a scalar code with unpredictable conditional branches instead of a fast branch-less SIMD code. Such an issue is not rare. I think the biggest gap can be get when computing parsing ASCII characters on server CPUs with 2 AVX-512 units.

"Just wondering about if better SW can bring more uplift than new node technology" Regarding this specific sentence, definitively yes! The interpreter overheads are huge and proper low-level optimizations can give a really huge boost in some cases. I personally got several times speed-ups of >100_000 while rewritting generic R/Python codes doing number crunching (physics and statistical computations) to highly optimized C++ codes (while not changing the algorithmic complexity of the code).

Choosing the right algorithm, with the right container can give even higher boost. It can transform codes taking decades to ones taking seconds. For more information about this, see computational complexity. For example a naive O(n**2) sort can be many order of magnitude slower than a O(n) radix sort on large input data (especially on architecture that can mitigate the memory latency like GPUs and if the target naive sort is not SIMD-friently). A simpler example is the fibonacci sequence (O(2**n) versus O(log n))

The answer to your question depends upon the programming language and how it is implemented, giving a wide range of variablity. You have a straight programming language with low library overhead (like C) and have a good optimizer, there is little to no performance loss due to using a high level language, assuming good programming practices are followed. A good compiler can optimize better than programmers can usually optimize assembly language by hand.
That performance can be sabotaged in C by doing stupid things like passing structures by value. There is nothing a system can do about bad programming.
There are languages with high library overhead, such as employing garbage collection for memory management. That gives a performance hit.
Another step down is interpreted languages, that give an even greater performance hit.
In reality, the biggest performance hits tend to be from internal hardware interfaces, rather than inherent issues with programming languages. CPUs tend to be much faster than system buses so they waste a lot of processing power inherently. The new apple processors are doing everything they can to eliminate the system bus issue.
